# How to modify the Verilog code to avoid multiple drivers?

Tags: verilog, fpga

Quartus 11.0 says:

> Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "n[9]"

for the following code:

```
module make_counter(h, clk, P);

input wire h;
input wire clk; 
output wire P;
reg r=1'b1;
reg[9:0] n=10'b0000000000;

always @(posedge h)
begin
    n<=0;
end

always @(negedge clk)
begin
if(n<600) 
    n<=n+1'b1;

if(n==106)  
    r<=1'b0;
else if(n==517)  
    r<=1'b1;
else;
end
assign P=r;

endmodule
```

---

[########### image is here ###########](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Dmk.png)

---

zhe image is what i want. when flag1 start set n=0, and count clk;
  when count to flag2, set P=0; when count to red arrow, set P=1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `h` is synchronous to `clk`, simply sample `h` and figure out when the sample value is low and the current value is high (e.g. `h` rose). This way `n` is assigned within one always block (which is required for synthesis) and everything is is the same clocking domain.

```
always @(negedge clk) begin
  past_h <= h;
  if(!past_h && h) begin // detect 0->1
    n <= 10'h000;
  end
  else begin
    n <= n + 1'b1;
  end
end
```

If `h` is asynchronous, then things get more complicated to keep the signal clean. In which case I recommend reading [Clock Domain Crossing (CDC) Design & Verification Techniques](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2008Boston_CDC.pdf) by Cliff Cummings

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says, there are multiple drivers for `n[9]`, and actually all of `n` and `r`, since `n` and `r` are both driven in the `initial` and the `always`, and when synthesizing the design, there can be only one driver for a reg.  And `n` is driven in multiple `always` blocks.

For synthesis, a reg should be driven from only one `always` block.

For the multiple always blocks where `n` is driven, combine these to only one, and use only one clock, e.g. `clk`.

If the purpose is to assign a default value for `n` and `r`, then make that in the declaration, and remove the `initial`, like:

```
reg r = 1'b1;
reg[9:0] n = 0;
```

However, consider adding a reset signal if possible, then then use this reset signal to assign reset values to the regs, either synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: how about this: always @(posedge h)   n<=0;  ?

Comment: That is equivalent to `always @(posedge h) begin n<=0; end`, but it is unrelated to the question and problem of multiple drivers.

Comment: i modify the code as your advice above, but still, Quartus 11.0 says: Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net[9] ....

Comment: the expression:  n<=0;  n<=n+1'b1;   is the error point, but how to solve it?

Comment: Have you removed the `initial` block?  I wonder why the warning says `net[9]`, since there is no net named `net` in the code... copy paste error or compiling the wrong code?  Also see answer update about multiple always blocks.

Comment: The `n` is still assigned in two different `always` blocks, but there can't be multiple drivers in synthesis.  See the update to my answer.

Comment: Only assign to `n` in a single `always` block, so combine the 2 blocks to one, which should probably use `posedge clk`, since that is the usual, but it actually depends on the functionality you want, but unless `h` is like async reset, it does not make sense to have that in the sensitivity list.

Comment: zhe whole error meaage is: Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "n[9]" at  main.v(123)

Comment: my target is: when h posedge come, start count clk, if count to 105, r set 0, if count to 517, r set to 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move the posedge h into the same always block as the negedge clock and sample h and clk based on the input logic. If h goes low before the negedge of clk then something like this may work.

```
module make_counter(h, clk, P);

input wire h;
input wire clk; 
output wire P;
reg r=1'b1;
reg[9:0] n=10'b0000000000;



always @(negedge clk, posedge h)
begin
if(h==1'b1)
    n<=0;
if(n<600) 
    n<=n+1'b1;

if(n==106)  
    r<=1'b0;
else if(n==517)  
    r<=1'b1;
else;
end
assign P=r;

endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

i think it will help you out. i have compiled this one in xilinx 14.5 synthesis is done.

```
    module make_counter(h, clk, P);
    input wire h;
    input wire clk; 

output wire P;
reg r=1'b1;
reg[9:0] n=10'b0000000000;


task cpu_write;
   begin
      @ (posedge h);
    n <= 0;
      @ (posedge clk);
      if(n<600) 
    n<=n+1'b1;
    if(n==106)  
        r<=1'b0;
    else if(n==517)  
        r<=1'b1;
    else;
    end
  endtask
assign P=r;

endmodule
```